# Why does rich texts on strapi keeps markups visible in my app

Tags: reactjs, markdown, text-editor, strapi, react-quill

I have some problems with the strapi rich text editor.
When I type some text, the format doesn't appear at all in the render of my app. No line break. Plus, the markDown code stays visible.

I tried by replacing the strapi text editor by react-quill and I still have the same problem. I type some text in the admin panel and when I render my app, all the html is visible.

What did I miss?

[image: screen shot of the app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have to "say" to React that the content is HTML.

Could you try using the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop?

Another solution would be to use `react-markdown`, as explained in [this tutorial](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-blog-with-next-react-js-strapi).

Comment: Ok. It wasn't specified in the tuto, but I need to import react-quill or react-markdown in each page of the frontend where I use some rich text?

Comment: that makes sens. Thank you, I missed that part of the tutorial